# Convert HTML dictionary to PYTHON dictionary

Tags: python, html, arrays, list, dictionary

i need to **get values** only for **Czechia** country from this website list "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries" and store like a **variable dictionary** in ptyhon.

Like this:

```
Czechia = {"cases":434,"todayCases":0,"deaths":0,"todayDeaths":0,"recovered":3,"active":431,"critical":2}
```

Comment: Hello. While your question clear , it is not showcasing your efforts at all.  Can you please share what you have tried and what did not work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to GET the JSON data from your server URL, then construct a new dictionary with `country` as the key:

```
from requests import get

URL = "https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries"

req = get(URL).json()

result = {obj['country']: {k: v for k, v in obj.items() if k != 'country'} for obj in req}

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'China': {'cases': 80894, 'todayCases': 13, 'deaths': 3237, 'todayDeaths': 11, 'recovered': 69614, 'active': 8043, 'critical': 2622}, 'Italy': {'cases': 31506, 'todayCases': 0, 'deaths': 2503, 'todayDeaths': 0, 'recovered': 2941, 'active': 26062, 'critical': 2060}...
```

Now you can access your data in **O(1)** time instead of doing a **O(N)** linear scan:

```
print(result["Czechia"])
# {'cases': 464, 'todayCases': 30, 'deaths': 0, 'todayDeaths': 0, 'recovered': 3, 'active': 461, 'critical': 2}
```

**Note:** Its probably also safe to ensure `req.status_code` is 200 OK or whatever else you expect to receive from the server.

Answer (score 1):

While the [RoadRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5238915/roadrunner) 's answers solves your problem, I am just giving you the one other way of doing it using python's `urllib` module.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
##import ast
import json


def Corona_Tracker():
    res = urlopen('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries')
    result = res.read().strip()
    result_str = json.loads(result)
    return result_str
if __name__ == "__main__":
    result_str=Corona_Tracker()
    while True:
        for data in result_str:
            if data['country'] == "India":
                print(data)
```

Just replace `India` with your country , it gives the below output

```
>>> {'country': 'India', 'cases': 148, 'todayCases': 5, 'deaths': 3, 'todayDeaths': 0, 'recovered': 14, 'active': 131, 'critical': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]:  import requests
   ...:  import json
   ...:
   ...:  data = requests.get('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries').json()
   ...:  result = next(item for item in data if item["country"] == "Czechia")
   ...:  print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
{
    "country": "Czechia",
    "cases": 464,
    "todayCases": 30,
    "deaths": 0,
    "todayDeaths": 0,
    "recovered": 3,
    "active": 461,
    "critical": 2
}

In [2]:
```